# Delay evaluation but need to plot

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

I've defined a mathematica function that makes a taylor series of a function.

```
s4a[n_] := Normal[Series[f4a[a], {a, 0, n}]]
```

But I cannot plot it

```
Plot[s4a[5], {a,-2,2}]
...
General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

I understand I have a problem like described here: [General::ivar is not a valid variable when plotting - what actually causes this and how to avoid it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this)

But I cannot define

```
s4a[n_] = Normal[Series[f4a[a], {a, 0, n}]]
Series::serlim: Series order specification n is not a machine-sized integer.
```

So how do I define a function that makes a series of order $n$ and can be plotted?

Edit:

I guess `Plot[Evaluate[s4a[5]],{a,-2,2}]` works though. Maybe this is the best solution

Comment: Does `Plot[Evaluate[s4a[5]], {a, -2, 2}]` give what you expect?

Comment: yes. thank you. i made an edit about that a few seconds before your comment. i guess that would be the simplest solution. what does it do though? "causes expr to be evaluated even if it appears as the argument of a function whose attributes specify that it should be held unevaluated." I thought the problem was that evaluation was occurring too early

Comment: Should probably be a duplicate of this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48980/4999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because Plot assigns a numeric value to the variable a and then evaluates the expression s4a[5]. Because of the set delayed operator, the expression that is actually evaluated inside Plot is probably something like:

```
Normal[Series[f4a[-2], {-2, 0, n}]]
```

This obviously would return an error.

You can force Plot to evaluate its argument first by wrapping it in Evaluate or using the following option:

```
Plot[s4a[5], {a, -2, 2}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Comment: I see. Thank you. One counter intuitive thing is that the error message before `further output of General::ivar will be suppressed` is `General::ivar: -1.99992 is not a valid variable.` This made me thing that Plot was looking for a symbolic form.